# How do I join two tables in SQL limiting the second table data depending on the first one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, join

I have two tables looking something like this:

```
IMP DATE        CAT
A   03/03/2016  1
B   04/04/2016  1
C   09/09/2016  2
D   01/01/2017  1
E   02/02/2017  1
F   03/03/2017  2
G   04/04/2017  2
```

===================

```
EXP DATE        CAT
H   01/01/2016  1
I   05/05/2016  1
J   07/07/2016  2
K   11/11/2016  2
L   01/01/2017  1
M   03/03/2017  1
N   04/04/2017  2
O   05/05/2017  2
```

I want to join the first table to the second one but limit the lines joined from the second table by the latest date on the first table (per category).

The result I'm looking for would be every row in both tables except Item "M" (because Cat 1 in Table 1 has a latest date of February) and Item "O" (because Cat 2 in Table 1 has a latest date of April).

I've tried conditionalds within a where clause in the 2nd table but haven't got far.

Is there a simple way to do this? Any help is appreciated. I'm using SQL Server 2008 by the way.

Comment: Can we see the query you've got so far? What's the datatype of the DATE column?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  If you want all rows in both tables, why are you talking about a `join`?

Comment: Can result have rows which have different categories?

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is specifically about using `join`.  That suggests a query like this:

```
select . . . 
from (select t1.*, max(t1.date) over (partition by t1.cat) as maxdate
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.cat = t2.cat and t2.date <= t1.maxdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Desire output and its format is still not clear.

are you looking for this ?

```
;With CTE as
(
select *, row_number()over(partition by cat order by DATEs desc) rn
from @table1
)
--select * from cte
--where rn=1

select * from cte t1
left join @table2 t2
on t1.CAT=t2.CAT and t2.DATEs<=t1.DATEs
where rn=1
```